# Fire drop event attached to a rectangle line wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop, drawing

I'm trying to fire the drag drop event attached to a rectangle line. The DragEventHandler is firing when the user drops on the line, but i need to fire the drag event even when the user drops it around(say 5 units around the actual line). As shown in the attached image.

I need to increase the drop area around the line, without increasing it's width.

[image]

Rectangle line = new Rectangle();

`line.Drop += (sender, args) => { //Do some work }`

Comment: Why not implementing this on the form? You got the coordinates and so you can check if it is near the line..

Comment: drop event will be attached to the line during it's creation. Hence i won't be knowing at which position(x,y) the user will drag and drop. But if it is on the line, i will use args.GetPosition(canvas) to get the line x,y position.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, add the Drag/Drop events to the form containing the line. Example:

```
    private void Form1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point relative =  PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        if ((relative.X > label1.Left - 10) && (relative.X < label1.Left + label1.Width + 10)  && (relative.Y > label1.Top - 10) && (relative.Y < label1.Top + label1.Height + 10))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
         else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }
```

(I've tested it with a label, replace this with your needs)